# Reference to inner node in firebase in Ionic 3

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, ionic2, ionic3

[image]

I'm New to firebase and ionic framework. 
Here you can see we have **two types of USER_ROLES** 
each user role have unique key.
And **all users are registered under the specific USER ROLE KEY**
user also have unique key.it is stored as **user_id**.

Now I want to know if I have **user_id:dAUKZtGlOnhwINle1mj5gmcOI7g2** and
how to get **user_name & user_role_name** in my application?
I can't find out how to reference to user_id. 
I have tried a lot, but I couldn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found the solution , I don't know is it correct approach or not. but it is working

```
this.oAngularFireDatabase.database.ref('Users').orderByKey()
          .on('value', snapshot => {
            if (snapshot.hasChildren()) {
              snapshot.forEach(innerSnap => {
                if (innerSnap.hasChild(user.uid)) {
                  this.loggedInUserName = innerSnap.child(user.uid).child("user_name").val();
                }
              })
            }
          })
```